# pyramid add_route() according to default_locale_name variable from .ini

Tags: python, pyramid, gettext

On a pyramid project, I'd like to set the routes according to the pyramid.default_locale_name variable defined in the .ini.
I mean, for eg, I already have _('/welcome') which is in .pot and .po files, already translated in different languagues like '/bienvenido' for spanish language and '/bienvenue' for french one.

As I need differents instances of this pyramid project, due to differents servers, differents options, differents changes in DB... what whould be the best way to stay it simple and not too much ugly? :)

Any suggestion are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

```
[app:main]
use = edd:YourApp
pyramid.reload_templates = true
pyramid.debug_authorization = false
pyramid.debug_notfound = false
...
pyramid.default_locale_name = en
...
```

For pyramid.default_locale_name variable, the value supplied here is used as the default locale name when a locale negotiator is not registered. Read the following [Localization-Related Deployment Settings](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/i18n.html#localization-deployment-settings) to set up routes to translated directories.

If you want to load different python modules with different settings, I think you should take a look at this project [pyramid_settings](https://github.com/niktto/pyramid_settings/)

Hope that's what you're looking for.